# How to include function text in a formula?

Tags: crystal-reports

This is probably a very simple question, but i'm trying to write a formula which will display text depending on the value that is being run.
However, the text i require has the word "Floor" in it which is a function, therefore when i save the formula it warns me saying There is an error in this formula. Do you want to save it anyway?

Is there a way i can include the word Floor in the text, such as putting '' around the word?

For example

IF {database.column} = 3 THEN "3rd Floor"

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. "Floor" does not give me a warning like Floor does.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think CR is expecting an `Else` statement

```
IF {database.column} = 3 THEN 
    "3rd Floor"
else  ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was the fact that i had a line break in it without specifying it with Chrw().

Answer (score 0):

[image: Follow Steps]

**Right-Click on feild then Formate Object & insert formula in Display string**

```
IF {database.column} = 3 THEN '3rd Floor'
```